# In how many different ways can we pick n objects out of (3n+1)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways , can we **pick n obejcts out of (3n+1)** , when n of these are identical. Answer: $2^{2n}$ : We can either pick exactly 0,1,...,n out of those (2n+1) different objects and these facts do exlude each other .Hence, there are $\sum_{k=0}^{n}C(2n+1,k)$ to do this. But we know: $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}C(2n+1,k)=2^{2n+1}=C(2n+1,0)+C(2n+1,1)+...+C(2n+1,n)+C(2n+1,n+1)+..+C(2n+1,2n+1)=C(2n+1,0)+C(2n+1,1)+...+C(2n+1,n)+C(2n+1,n)+..+C(2n+1,0)=2*\sum_{k=0}^{n}C(2n+1,k)=2^{2n+1} \rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n}C(2n+1,k)=2^{2n}$

> Can you help me identify my error in this approach: Since n objects out of (3n+1) are identical , the remaining (2n+1) objects are different. Hence, we only need to determine which of those(different ones) we are going to pick , because the others ones, from the  set of "n identical" ones , can only be chosen in 1 way . First, of all we can pick from those (2n+1) at most n. So, we are not going to pick for sure $(2n+1)-n= n+1$. We can pick those "outsiders" in $C(2n+1,n+1)$ ways. Now, let's say , that for each element ,we chose to pick ,we write a "1" above it and a "0" otherwise. Right now , we have already decided which (n+1) out of (2n+1) are not going to be chosen for sure. Out of the remaining n, we put a "1" for each we chose and "0" for those we don't $\rightarrow 2^n$ ways to do this. So in total : $C(2n+1,n+1)*2^n$.
> What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

When you decide which elements are "not going to be chosen for sure", but then don't choose some of the remaining elements either, that gives you many ways to represent the same outcome.

Say that the $3n+1$ elements are "A A B C D E F". Here are two separate possibilities you count:

- I decide on D E F as the "outsiders". From the remaining A A B C, I pick A B.
- I decide on C D E as the "outsiders". From the remaining A A B F, I pick A B.

The ultimate outcome "A B" is the same, but it's counted twice. (Actually, there's two more ways to count it, by picking C D F or C E F as the "outsiders".)

---

Instead, I would do casework not on the "outsiders" but on how many of the identical elements you choose. If you choose $k$ of the identical elements, then you're left with $\binom{2n+1}{n-k}$ choices for the remainder, and then you can sum over all $k$.

Comment: so I am counitng twice , cases that those that I leave out at first ,happen to be the same with those I don't pick after ... thank you! you are right